# Selenium Click A Button, Using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried to figure this out for a while - no luck.

I want to click this button:

```html
<button name="showMoreButton" data-test-id="show-more-button" aria-label="Show More" type="button" class="uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-has-text uitk-button-primary">Show More </button >
```

I have been trying things like this I have found all over the place, but none work:

```js
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.xpath("//button[@data-test-id='show-more-button']").click()
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.cssSelector(".uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-has-text uitk-button-primary")).click()
```

I think the first failure occurred because Selenium appears to be unable to handle "data-test-id" - something that strikes me a curious weakness...

I can't understand why the second failure occurred.

Thanks so much for any help.

Ellie The Good Dog

Comment: What happens on the first one?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: It's work code that I'm not able to post here, so I can't post a "MRE". Sorry if my question is bad - I thought this was like a 30 second answer from someone more experienced, but maybe it just won't work. Thanks all.

Comment: The first call is missing a closing parentheses before `.click()`.

Comment: Oh god - you are right.  Thanks for that. Now I've been upgraded to AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'.

Comment: It's supposed to be in all capitals -- `By.XPATH`

Comment: You are a saint John - now I get 'str' object is not callable !

Comment: You're using `By.XPATH` as a separate function, but it's not.  It's just the first argument to `find_element()`, like so: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//something')`  I think you must have copied from a Java selenium example, but the Python version is a bit different.

Comment: OK thanks a bunch - I'm going to have to research it, I'm definitely lost.

Comment: Ellie, just use this:  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-test-id='show-more-button']").click()`.  @JohnGordon was just pointing out that the syntax you were using, needed a comma between `XPATH` at the actual xpath, not a parenthesis. BTW that syntax is usually only used when you incorporate WebDriverWait around it

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to deal with that. Here is a reliable solution.

**Use Explicit wait**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'showMoreButton')))
element.click()
```

You would need to import from the below line :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

or if you want to use XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR then you could try something like given below :

**CSS :**

```
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='showMoreButton'].uitk-button.uitk-button-medium.uitk-button-has-text.uitk-button-primary")
element_to_click.click()
```

**XPATH :**

```
element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Show More')]")
element_to_click.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code as below. You are missing one parenthesis and writing wrongly .find_element method.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-test-id='show-more-button']").click()
```

You can also use  as below

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-has-text uitk-button-primary").click()
```